# Gitlab and Exim conflicting 'from' addresses when sending emails

Tags: gitlab, exim

I have installed Gitlab 8.15 and Exim 4.84 on CentOS 7

Whenever Gitlab sends a message, it should come from 'gitlab@mydomain.nl' which is correctly set in `config/gitlab.yml`.

If I look in the log, I see the following:

```
2016-12-21 21:50:02 cwd=/ 6 args: /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -f gitlab@mydomain.nl -- mypersonal@gmail.com
2016-12-21 21:50:02 1cJnpq-0001ZR-NG <= git@vps.mydomain.nl U=git P=local S=3859 id=585aeafaad130_175126f0b9c43854@vps.mydomain.nl.mail T="Reset password instructions" from <git@vps.mydomain.nl> for mypersonal@gmail.com
```

Note that between those 2 lines, the from address changed from `gitlab@mydomain.nl` to `git@vps.mydomain.nl` which is based on `user@FQDN`.

My external SMTP server then does a DKIM and SPF lookup on `vps.mydomain.nl`, instead of `mydomain.nl`, which fails and the mail is rejected.

I am not sure where this change happens and how I should fix this. Is this something on Gitlab side or something on Exim side?

The relevant parts from my exim configuration:

```
begin routers
mysmtphost_email:
  driver = manualroute
  domains = ! +local_domains
  ignore_target_hosts = 127.0.0.0/8
  transport = mysmtphost_relay
  route_list = * vps.mysmtphost.email::587
  no_more

(...)

begin transports
mysmtphost_relay:
  driver = smtp
  port = 587
  hosts_require_auth = <; $host_address
  hosts_require_tls = <; $host_address
```

Answer (score 1):

Just found out the user `git` was not part of the `trusted_users` directive in the `exim.conf` file. I changed it to include the user as follows:
`trusted_users = mail:apache:passenger:git`

I came to this conclusion since mails sent by other Rails applications running as user `passenger` were being sent correctly as specified by the from address. Then I noticed `passenger` being part of this directive and `git` not.

From the Exim documentation:

> Trusted users are always permitted to use the -f option or a leading
>   “From ” line to specify the envelope sender of a message that is
>   passed to Exim through the local interface (see the -bm and -f options
>   below). See the untrusted_set_sender option for a way of permitting
>   non-trusted users to set envelope senders.

http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_exim_command_line.html#SECTtrustedadmin

> Processes running as root or the Exim user are always trusted. Other
>   trusted users are defined by the trusted_users or trusted_groups
>   options. In the absence of -f, or if the caller is not trusted, the
>   sender of a local message is set to the caller’s login name at the
>   default qualify domain.